# BlenderGIS import call from python script

Tags: python, add-on, import

My goal is to import a .shp file into blender within my python script. I found the add-on [BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) that offers this functionality. I can add the add-on to blender make it work "manually", but I want to call the import function from a python script.

I am new to Blender and I cannot find what the right way is to import a add-on/BlenderGIS into a python script.

Among other things, I tried the following:

```
import bpy
import sys
import os

dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
if not dir in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(dir )

import io_shapefile

file = "path/to/file.shp"

bpy.ops.importgis(file)
```

This gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'BPyOpsSubMod' object is not callable
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to import a .shp from a python script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"bpy.ops.importgis(file)" is not a function. The right way to import a .shp file with BlenderGIS is:

```
bpy.ops.importgis.shapefile("EXEC_DEFAULT", filepath=file)
```

where the first parametere can be one of these options:

'INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN', 'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS', 'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA', 'INVOKE_SCREEN', 'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN', 'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS', 'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA', 'EXEC_SCREEN'

So, the following code will import a .shp file:

```
import bpy
file = "/path/to/file.shp"
bpy.ops.importgis.shapefile("EXEC_DEFAULT", filepath=file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the operator name when you mouse over it, in this case `bpy.ops.importgis.shapefile()`

Now in the python console type in command and using autocomplete <kbd>ctrl-space</kbd>

```
>> bpy.ops.importgis.shapefile(
shapefile()
bpy.ops.importgis.shapefile(filepath="", filter_glob="*.shp", useFieldElev=False, fieldElevName="", useFieldExtrude=False, fieldExtrudeName="", extrusionAxis='Z', angCoords=False, separateObjects=False, useFieldName=False, fieldObjName="")
```

You get the operator call and the parameters.  Testing with a local filepath

```
>>> bpy.ops.importgis.shapefile(filepath="/mnt/.../GDAL/contour.shp")
Read shapefile...
Feature type : PolyLine
DBF fields : ['id', 'elev']
0%
10%
20%
...
90%
100%
Imported mesh had some problem, check the result!
{'FINISHED'}

>>>
```